# How to remove whitespace from a string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, input, dynamic

I have an array of size 100. I read string input from a the user and store it in the array. The user input is less than 100 characters. How would I create a new array which is the exact length of the input (without the trailing whitespace at the end)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your code *as text*, formatted as a code block, instead of describing it. Show example input and expected output. See [ask] and [tour].

Comment: By trailing whitespace do you mean the characters 'wasted' by the length of the string or is the user literally giving blank characters as input?

Comment: The `strdup` function is one option (but it's not part of the standard C library). You can write your own `strdup` function using `strlen`, `malloc` and `strcpy`. Just be sure that you allocate `strlen(str) + 1` bytes of memory, so there's room for the zero byte at the end of the string.

Comment: @user3386109 `strdup` is a part of the upcoming C23 standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of the "unused" characters (those after `'\0'`) and make an "exact copy":

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_str(char *base) {
  char *result = malloc(strlen(base) + 1);
  if (!result) exit(1);
  return strcpy(result, base);
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the string once you are done with it!